# read() and write() functions do not collaborate

Tags: c, linux

The task is to copy the sentence from one file to another and reverse it meanwhile.

There are no errors while compiling, original file contains certain sentence but that reverse one does not save in the second file.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    int file1 = open("a.txt", O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_TRUNC, 0777);

    write(file1, "How are you?", 12);

    lseek(file1, -1, SEEK_END);

    ////////////////////////////////

    char c;

    int file2 = open("b.txt", O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_TRUNC, 0777);

    while( read(file1, &c, 1) ) {

     write(file2, c, 1);
     lseek(file1, -1, SEEK_CUR);
    }

    ////////////////////////////////

    close(file1);
    close(file2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: shouldn't `lseek(file1, -1, SEEK_CUR);` be `lseek(file2, -1, SEEK_CUR);` ?

Comment: I want to put the sentence from file1 to file2 in reversed version, so every saved step I have to move a pointer from right to left in the file1. I think so.

Comment: @Apoorv - no, it shouldn't.

Comment: @csal - when you read a character from a file, you advance the file pointer. Subtracting 1 from the pointer after a (1 byte) read puts the file-pointer back at the same char. To look at the previous char, you'd need to subtract 2 from the current position, not 1. Also, your while loop wont exit. You should consider getting the length of file 1 and then use this number as the number of iterations in the loop.

Comment: @enhzflep - you are right. I changed it and included libs suggested in the post below and it works now like a charm. Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: @csal - you're welcome. Also, rather than hard-coding the length of the input file as 12 (as suggested in george's answer) consider using the return value of `lseek(file1, -1, SEEK_END);` - this will tell you the index of the last byte in the file. (add 1 to get the length of the file in bytes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your while loop to this:

```
    int i = 0;
    while( read(file1, &c, 1) ) {
        i++;
        write(file2, &c, 1);
        lseek(file1, -2, SEEK_CUR);

        if(i==12) // 12 is length of file which is being read.
            break;

    }
```

and included this:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
```

works at my side.

Comment: That's certainly a part of the problem, but not a solution by itself.

Comment: I changed it, but the problem still occurs.

Comment: @georgem - also, you can get the fileLength-1 from the result of `lseek(file1, -1, SEEK_END);`. If you add 1 to the return value of this call to lseek, you'll have (in this particular case) 12.

Comment: @enhzflep: sure I just wrote 12 to be quick. One could also have separate function to get file size and use that.

Comment: @enhzflep - it's a good idea. I will try to implement it in my code. Thank you again! I appreciate every pieces of advice, so it can help make my code more useful. :)